# Delete message older than 90 days from error/poison queue using masstransit

Tags: rabbitmq, azureservicebus, masstransit

Scenario:
I have windows service which reads messages from MessageBus using MassTransit. MessageBus can be configured to RabbitMQ or AzureService Bus.
If the message fails consistently after 5 times the message will be moved to another queue "publishToXYZ_Error"

Question:
I want to delete all the messages in "publishToXYZ_Error" which is older than 90 days using MassTransit.
or is there a way we can filter and consume messages which are older than 90 days using  MassTransit.

Example payload

```
{
  "messageId": "acdc0000-0e07-28f1-43d2-08d87c0aad48",
  "conversationId": "acdc0000-0e07-28f1-bc6c-08d87c081e05",
  "sourceAddress": "rabbitmq://localhost/MyComputer_dotnet_bus_iuqyyyyqyhwxnoksbdc8ab6erb?durable=false&autodelete=true",
  "destinationAddress": "rabbitmq://localhost/PublishToXYZ_delay?type=x-delayed-message&delayedType=fanout&bindexchange=PublishToXYZ",
  "messageType": [],

  "message": {

    "xyzEndPointId": "3",
    "actorMail": "temp65@gmail.com",
    "scoreBandTitle": "fail",
    "resultStatus": 2,
    "maxScore": 100,
    "totalScore": 10,
    "percentageScore": 77,
    "firstName": "ParticipantNameANA 11",

  },

  "sentTime": "2020-10-29T13:00:57.1637274Z",

  "headers": {
    "MT-Redelivery-Count": 5
  },

  "host": {
    "machineName": "Mycomputer",
    "processName": "dotnet",
    "processId": 38008,
    "frameworkVersion": "4.0.30319.42000",
    "massTransitVersion": "5.5.5.0",
    "operatingSystemVersion": "Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.19041.0"
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are talking about the error queue or the poison queue, or the [invalid message channel](https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/InvalidMessageChannel.html)

> MassTransit does nothing with that queue and woun't delete messages from there. You can do it yourself from the UI or using the management API or your broker.

I found a similar discussion : [MassTransit/RabbitMq Error queue - how to delete messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64008063/masstransit-rabbitmq-error-queue-how-to-delete-messages)

Please let me know if this is relevant.